# Problema con Firebase + Tealium

Tags: java, android, firebase

estoy teniendo un problema al configurar una maqueta con firebase y tealium (como gestor de etiquetas) en android (java).

Los eventos de firebase se envian correctamente pero no consigo recogerlos en tealium y no se donde puedo tener el fallo.

Os comparto la clase que uso para lanzar el evento y la clase de mapeo que proporciona tealium.

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

import com.tealium.internal.tagbridge.RemoteCommand;
import com.tealium.library.Tealium;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FireEvents extends AppCompatActivity {

    public FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    public static final String TEALIUM_MAIN = "Eventos";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setTitle("Eventos");

        mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);

        // this code sets up a config object and creates a Tealium instance; you should already have this code in your app
        //sustituido application por metodo getApplication
        Tealium.Config config = Tealium.Config.create(getApplication(), "accountName", "profileName", "dev");
        Tealium inst = Tealium.createInstance(TEALIUM_MAIN, config);

        // the following is the new code to add the Firebase Analytics Remote Command

        //sustituido application por metodo getApplication
        RemoteCommand firebase = new FirebaseRemoteCommand(getApplication());


        inst.addRemoteCommand(firebase);

        evPrueba();

    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(this, "Eventos", null /* class override */);
    }

    private void evPrueba (){

        Bundle product1 = new Bundle();
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "sku1234");  // ITEM_ID or ITEM_NAME is required
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Donut Friday Scented T-Shirt");
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Apparel/Men/Shirts");
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "Blue");
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google");
        product1.putDouble( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 29.99 );
        product1.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "USD" );
        product1.putLong( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.INDEX, 1 );     // Position of the item in the list

        Bundle product2 = new Bundle();
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "sku5678");
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, "Android Workout Capris");
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, "Apparel/Women/Pants");
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_VARIANT, "Black");
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_BRAND, "Google");
        product2.putDouble( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, 39.99 );
        product2.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "USD" );
        product2.putLong( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.INDEX, 2 );

        // Prepare ecommerce bundle
        ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
        items.add(product1);
        items.add(product2);

        String tipoEvento = "Product Impressions";

        Bundle ecommerceBundle = new Bundle();
        ecommerceBundle.putParcelableArrayList( "items", items );

        // Set relevant bundle-level parameters
        ecommerceBundle.putString( FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LIST, "Search Results" ); // List name


        // Log view_search_results or view_item_list event with ecommerce bundle
        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent( FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_SEARCH_RESULTS, ecommerceBundle );

    }  
}
```

Clase de mapeo proporcionada por tealium.
Esta clase la podeis encontrar tambien en la documentación oficial sobre este tema.

https://community.tealiumiq.com/t5/Installation-Libraries/Google-Analytics-for-Firebase-Mobile-Integration-Guide/ta-p/21200?advanced=false&collapse_discussion=true&q=firebase&search_type=thread

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Application;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.tealium.internal.tagbridge.RemoteCommand;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics;

/**
 * Note: to enable Debug logging, issue the following terminal command:
 * adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app [app rdns/package name]
 */
public final class FirebaseRemoteCommand extends RemoteCommand {

    private String KEY_SESSION_TIMEOUT = "firebase_session_timeout_seconds";
    private String KEY_MIN_SECONDS = "firebase_session_minimum_seconds";
    private String KEY_ANALYTICS_ENABLED = "firebase_analytics_enabled";
    // reserved for future use. log level can only be set
    private String KEY_LOG_LEVEL = "firebase_log_level";
    private String KEY_EVENT_NAME = "firebase_event_name";
    private String KEY_EVENT_PARAMS = "firebase_event_params";
    private  String KEY_SCREEN_NAME = "firebase_screen_name";
    private String KEY_SCREEN_CLASS = "firebase_screen_class";
    private  String KEY_USER_PROPERTY_NAME = "firebase_property_name";
    private String KEY_USER_PROPERTY_VALUE = "firebase_property_value";
    private String KEY_USER_ID = "firebase_user_id";
    private String KEY_COMMAND_NAME = "command_name";

    private static FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;
    private static Activity mCurrentActivity;
    private static Map<String, String> eventsMap;
    private static Map<String, String> params;

    public FirebaseRemoteCommand (Application application) {
        super("firebaseAnalytics", "Firebase Analytics Remote Command");
        Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks cb = createActivityLifecycleCallbacks();
        application.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(cb);
        initMaps();
    }

    public static Bundle jsonToBundle(JSONObject jsonObject) throws JSONException {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Iterator iter = jsonObject.keys();
        while(iter.hasNext()){
            String key = (String)iter.next();
            String value = jsonObject.getString(key);
            bundle.putString(key,value);
        }
        return bundle;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onInvoke(Response response){
        String command = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_COMMAND_NAME, null);

        String[] commandArray;
        // split the commands into an array
        commandArray = command.split(",");

        for (int j = 0, commandlen = commandArray.length; j < commandlen; j++) {
            command = commandArray[j];
            command = command.trim();
            switch (command) {
                case "config":
                    Integer timeout = Integer.parseInt(response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_SESSION_TIMEOUT, null)) * 1000;
                    Integer minSeconds = Integer.parseInt(response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_MIN_SECONDS, null)) * 1000;
                    String analyticsEnabled = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_ANALYTICS_ENABLED, null);
                    if (timeout != null) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setSessionTimeoutDuration(timeout.longValue());
                    }

                    if (minSeconds != null) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration(minSeconds.longValue());
                    }

                    if (analyticsEnabled != null && analyticsEnabled.equals("false")) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);
                    } else {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(true);
                    }
                    break;
                case "logEvent":
                    String eventName = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_EVENT_NAME, null);
                    JSONObject params = response.getRequestPayload().optJSONObject(KEY_EVENT_PARAMS);
                    Bundle paramBundle;
                    Bundle normalizedBundle = new Bundle();
                    try {
                        paramBundle = jsonToBundle(params);
                        for (String k: paramBundle.keySet()) {
                            normalizedBundle.putString(mapParams(k), paramBundle.getString(k));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        normalizedBundle = null;
                    }
                    if (eventName != null && params != null) {
                        String ev = mapEventNames(eventName);
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(ev, normalizedBundle);
                    }
                    break;
                case "setScreenName":
                    String screenName = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_SCREEN_NAME, null);
                    String screenClass = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_SCREEN_CLASS, null);
                    if (screenName != null) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setCurrentScreen(mCurrentActivity, screenName, screenClass);
                    }
                    break;
                case "setUserProperty":
                    String propertyName = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_USER_PROPERTY_NAME, null);
                    String propertyValue = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_USER_PROPERTY_VALUE, null);
                    if (propertyName != null && propertyValue != null) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserProperty(propertyName, propertyValue);
                    }
                    break;
                case "setUserId":
                    String userId = response.getRequestPayload().optString(KEY_USER_ID, null);
                    if (userId != null) {
                        mFirebaseAnalytics.setUserId(userId);
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
        response.send();
    }

    private static String mapEventNames(String eventName) {

        String name = eventsMap.get(eventName);
        if (name == null) {
            return eventName;
        }
        return name;
    }

    private static String mapParams(String param) {
        String paramName = params.get(param);
        if (paramName == null) {
            return param;
        }
        return paramName;
    }

    // these maps are used to map Tealium event names (standard for Swift and Java Firebase Remote Command) to Firebase's own public constants
    private static void initMaps(){
        // the following are documented in the Firebase docs, but missing from the Event class
        // the values set are the values provided in the documentation
        final String FIREBASE_EVENT_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS = "campaign_details";
        final String FIREBASE_EVENT_CHECKOUT_PROGRESS = "checkout_progress";
        final String FIREBASE_EVENT_REMOVE_FROM_CART = "remove_from_cart";
        final String FIREBASE_EVENT_SET_CHECKOUT_OPTION = "set_checkout_option";
        eventsMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
        eventsMap.put("add_payment_info", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_PAYMENT_INFO);
        eventsMap.put("add_to_cart", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_CART);
        eventsMap.put("add_to_wishlist", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_WISHLIST);
        eventsMap.put("app_open", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.APP_OPEN);
        eventsMap.put("event_begin_checkout", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.BEGIN_CHECKOUT);
        eventsMap.put("event_campaign_details", FIREBASE_EVENT_CAMPAIGN_DETAILS);
        eventsMap.put("event_checkout_progress", FIREBASE_EVENT_CHECKOUT_PROGRESS);
        eventsMap.put("event_earn_virtual_currency", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.EARN_VIRTUAL_CURRENCY);
        eventsMap.put("event_ecommerce_purchase", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ECOMMERCE_PURCHASE);
        eventsMap.put("event_generate_lead", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.GENERATE_LEAD);
        eventsMap.put("event_join_group", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.JOIN_GROUP);
        eventsMap.put("event_level_up", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LEVEL_UP);
        eventsMap.put("event_login", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN);
        eventsMap.put("event_post_score", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.POST_SCORE);
        eventsMap.put("event_present_offer", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PRESENT_OFFER);
        eventsMap.put("event_purchase_refund", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.PURCHASE_REFUND);
        eventsMap.put("event_remove_cart", FIREBASE_EVENT_REMOVE_FROM_CART);
        eventsMap.put("event_search", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SEARCH);
        eventsMap.put("event_select_content", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT);
        eventsMap.put("event_set_checkout_option", FIREBASE_EVENT_SET_CHECKOUT_OPTION);
        eventsMap.put("event_share", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SHARE);
        eventsMap.put("event_signup", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SIGN_UP);
        eventsMap.put("event_spend_virtual_currency", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SPEND_VIRTUAL_CURRENCY);
        eventsMap.put("event_tutorial_begin", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.TUTORIAL_BEGIN);
        eventsMap.put("event_tutorial_complete", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.TUTORIAL_COMPLETE);
        eventsMap.put("event_unlock_achievement", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.UNLOCK_ACHIEVEMENT);
        eventsMap.put("event_view_item", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM);
        eventsMap.put("event_view_item_list", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_ITEM);
        eventsMap.put("event_view_search_results", FirebaseAnalytics.Event.VIEW_SEARCH_RESULTS);
        // params
        // the following are documented in the Firebase docs, but missing from the Event class
        // the values set are the values provided in the documentation
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_ACLID = "aclid";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_AFFILIATION = "affiliation";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CP1 = "cp1";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CAMPAIGN = "campaign";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CHECKOUT_OPTION = "checkout_option";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CHECKOUT_STEP = "checkout_step";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CONTENT = "content";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CREATIVE_NAME = "creative_name";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_CREATIVE_SLOT = "creative_slot";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_INDEX = "index";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_BRAND = "item_brand";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_LIST = "item_list";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_VARIANT = "item_variant";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_MEDIUM = "medium";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_SOURCE = "source";
        final String FIREBASE_PARAM_TERM = "term";

        params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("param_achievement_id", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ACHIEVEMENT_ID);
        params.put("param_ad_network_click_id", FIREBASE_PARAM_ACLID);
        params.put("param_affiliation", FIREBASE_PARAM_AFFILIATION);
        params.put("param_cp1", FIREBASE_PARAM_CP1);
        params.put("param_campaign", FIREBASE_PARAM_CAMPAIGN);
        params.put("param_character", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CHARACTER);
        params.put("param_checkout_option", FIREBASE_PARAM_CHECKOUT_OPTION);
        params.put("param_checkout_step", FIREBASE_PARAM_CHECKOUT_STEP);
        params.put("param_content", FIREBASE_PARAM_CONTENT);
        params.put("param_content_type", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE);
        params.put("param_coupon", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.COUPON);
        params.put("param_creative_name", FIREBASE_PARAM_CREATIVE_NAME);
        params.put("param_creative_slot", FIREBASE_PARAM_CREATIVE_SLOT);
        params.put("param_currency", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY);
        params.put("param_destination", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.DESTINATION);
        params.put("param_end_date", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.END_DATE);
        params.put("param_flight_number", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.FLIGHT_NUMBER);
        params.put("param_group_id", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.GROUP_ID);
        params.put("param_index", FIREBASE_PARAM_INDEX);
        params.put("param_item_brand", FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_BRAND);
        params.put("param_item_category", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY);
        params.put("param_item_id", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID);
        params.put("param_item_list", FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_LIST);
        params.put("param_item_location_id", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_LOCATION_ID);
        params.put("param_item_name", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME);
        params.put("param_item_variant", FIREBASE_PARAM_ITEM_VARIANT);
        params.put("param_level", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.LEVEL);
        params.put("param_location", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.LOCATION);
        params.put("param_medium", FIREBASE_PARAM_MEDIUM);
        params.put("param_number_nights", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.NUMBER_OF_NIGHTS);
        params.put("param_number_pax", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.NUMBER_OF_PASSENGERS);
        params.put("param_number_rooms", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.NUMBER_OF_ROOMS);
        params.put("param_origin", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ORIGIN);
        params.put("param_price", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE);
        params.put("param_quantity", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY);
        params.put("param_score", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SCORE);
        params.put("param_search_term", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SEARCH_TERM);
        params.put("param_shipping", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SHIPPING);
        params.put("param_signup_method", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD);
        params.put("param_source", FIREBASE_PARAM_SOURCE);
        params.put("param_start_date", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.START_DATE);
        params.put("param_tax", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TAX);
        params.put("param_term", FIREBASE_PARAM_TERM);
        params.put("param_transaction_id", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TRANSACTION_ID);
        params.put("param_travel_class", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.TRAVEL_CLASS);
        params.put("param_value", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE);
        params.put("param_virtual_currency_name", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VIRTUAL_CURRENCY_NAME);
        params.put("param_user_signup_method", FirebaseAnalytics.Param.SIGN_UP_METHOD);
    }


    // Setup lifecycle callbacks to init FirebaseAnalytics. You may prefer to do this manually.
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH)
    private static Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks createActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {

        return new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                mCurrentActivity = activity;
                mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(mCurrentActivity.getApplicationContext());
            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

            }
        };
    }

}
```

Si alguien necesita algun dato mas que no dude en preguntar.

Un saludo y gracias por la ayuda gente.